# Render multiple objects crashes my browser with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have 3 objects to render in my scene. I tested 2 cases. First, I loaded my 3 objects as STL file, then I do not have a problem.
Second I divide each object as multiple surfaces, so I create BufferGeometry for each surface. There are multiple surfaces per object (1000 to 5000).
The reason of decomposing by surfaces is that I want the easiest way for highlighting surface selection. With this second method, my browser crash if I load the 3 objects. It can handle two objects.
This is my code:

```
function renderSurfaces(data, checkbox) {
var group = new THREE.Group();
var vertices = data.vertices;
var surfaces = data.surfaces;
var triangles = data.triangles;
//Generate all surface and add each one to the group    
var surfacesKeys = Object.keys(surfaces);
for (var i = 0; i < surfacesKeys.length; i++) {
    var indices = [];
    //Get all triangle ids composing the current surface
    var surfaceTriIds = surfaces[surfacesKeys[i]].surfaceTriIds;
    //Loop over surfaceTriIds
    var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
    for (var j = 0; j < surfaceTriIds.length; j++) {
        //Get vertices Id for one triangle
        var verticeTriangleIds = triangles[surfaceTriIds[j]];
        //Set triangle indices
        indices.push(verticeTriangleIds[0]);
        indices.push(verticeTriangleIds[1]);
        indices.push(verticeTriangleIds[2]);
        //           
    }
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setIndex(indices);
    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xAAAAAA,
        specular: 0x111111,
        shininess: 200
    }));
    group.add(obj);
}
scene.add(group);    
camera.lookAt(group.position);

render();
```

}

Is there a way to render my objects surface by surface?

Answer (score 0):

your code is a bit jankey..
afaik you allocate:

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
```

but then never do anything with it... and later on do

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
```

But regardless.. making a geometry per face is overkill.
If you just want to hilight a face...
Maybe try making a .clone() of the original geometry, adding it to a .clone() of the mesh... change the material on that mehs to be a different material to hilight the triangle, then use geometry.setDrawRange to only draw the triangle you are interested in:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.setDrawRange

Are you trying to do face picking with the mouse?

Comment: First, "var geom", I forgot to delete it. Second, yes my object is composed by multiple surfaces ( 1 or more triangles). Right now, I render my object using only one BufferGeometry, then I will try to highlight my surface as you suggest. I use Raycaster with the mouse.

Comment: I might find the reason why it crashes. For each surface I do not change my vertices size, I always consider my entire object vertices.